# Textbox hover background image moves and re-sizes

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui, textbox, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have attempted to put in a background image on a `Kendo UI` `Textbox`.

It's all well when you don't hover over it.

[image]

But as soon as you hover over it, this happens:

[image]

How do I fix this? When I hover and click into the `Textbox`, the image needs to stay at the same place.

Here is the `HTML` for adding the Textbox:

```
@Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(vm => vm.Username)
```

Here is the `CSS` for adding the background in:

```
#Username.k-textbox{

    background-image:url(/images/User_Icon.svg);       
}

input.k-textbox{
    background-size:19px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:12px 50%;       
    outline: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Looking at your code there isn't any hover code in your css, so it's hard to find the bug.

Comment: I would imagine the hover code being part of `Kendo UI`, I have added the `HTML` code in now too which I use to add the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my own problem. I needed to override the hover setting for the `Textbox` with `CSS`.

Here is the additional code added:

```
input.k-textbox:hover{
    background-size:19px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:12px 50%;
}
```